# Pandas : Multiple key values to be matched in df.replace()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this Dataframe:

```
     name     status  pos
0    Air TU   D       jan
1    AirTU N  L       dec
2    Air-TU   D       feb
3    NorTU.   L       jan
4    KolTU.   N       feb
.
.
.
```

I am trying to replace the all 3 versions of AirTU with AirTU (in my real dataset the number is much higher), and status by D by I and Jan by Nov:

```
df.replace({'status': {'D': 'I'},
            'pos': {'Jan':'Nov'},
            'name': {'Air TU': 'AirTU', 'Air-TU':'AirTU', 'AirTU N':'AirTU' }})
```

this is a simplified version of the dataset I am working with and It became very cumbersome after trying to do it for multiple names.
I want to combine a group of strings that can be matched as a key so I tried a frozenset:

```
df.replace({'status': {'D': 'I'},
            'pos': {'Jan':'Nov'},
            'name': { frozenset({'Air TU','Air-TU','AirTU N'}) :'AirTU' }})
```

This doesn't throw any errors but the names are not replaced for some reason.
I then tried with a tuple since all our elements are immutable :

```
df.replace({'status': {'D': 'I'},
            'pos': {'Jan':'Nov'},
            'name': { tuple({'Air TU','Air-TU','AirTU N'}) :'AirTU' }})
```

but it throws this error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6803,) (2,)
```

Is there a way to group the to match/keys to be replaced instead of repeating them independently ?
I took a very good look at pandas documentation but all the examples they give are for a one key in my situation.

Comment: Why don't you normalize the string? By normalizing I mean making 'Air TU','Air TU','AirTU N' all "airtu" (lowercase, no spaces). You could use pandas' `str.replace` to replace spaces and N with an empty character and `str.lowercase`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `dict.fromkeys`

```
df.replace({
    'status': {'D': 'I'},
    'pos': {'Jan': 'Nov'},
    'name': dict.fromkeys(['Air TU', 'Air TU', 'AirTU N'], 'AirTU')
})
```

---

```
     name status  pos
0   AirTU      I  jan
1   AirTU      L  dec
2  Air-TU      I  feb
3  NorTU.      L  jan
4  KolTU.      N  feb
```

Comment: This what I am trying to do but it's giving me TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'.
I think it's because I have other elements that I am matching inside name like this:
'name': { dict.fromkeys(['Air TU', 'Air TU', 'AirTU N'], 'AirTU') , 'Kol TU' : 'KolTU', 'Bol Air': 'BolAir' }

Comment: In that case you can use: `'name':  { **dict.fromkeys(['Air TU', 'Air TU', 'AirTU N'], 'AirTU') , 'Kol TU' : 'KolTU', 'Bol Air': 'BolAir' }`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this with pandas alone.

What you can do is use a different, condensed, format and unpack it:

```
d = {'status': {'D': 'I'},
     'pos': {'Jan':'Nov'},
     'name': {('Air TU', 'Air-TU', 'AirTU N'): 'Air-TU'},
     }

df.replace({k: {k3: v for k2, v in d2.items() 
                for k3 in (k2 if isinstance(k2, tuple) else [k2])}
            for k, d2 in d.items()})
```

Another option is to try to use a regex or string operations to make the match.

```
df.replace({'status': {'D': 'I'},
            'pos': {'Jan':'Nov'},
            'name': {'AirTU|Air TU|Air-TU': 'AirTU'}},
          regex=True)
```

Or, condensed:

```
df.replace({'status': {'D': 'I'},
            'pos': {'Jan':'Nov'},
            'name': {'Air[- ]?TU( N)?': 'Air-TU'}},
          regex=True)
```

Output:

```
     name status  pos
0  Air-TU      I  jan
1  Air-TU      L  dec
2  Air-TU      I  feb
3  NorTU.      L  jan
4  KolTU.      N  feb
```

Comment: Think I will have to go with regex. Thank you

Comment: @Domarius I added an example for the regex